# Could a faulty stove burner trip the circuit breaker?

Tags: stove

I have a four-burner stove and recently every time I switch on one of the burners it's tripping my main circuit breaker. It began with only one burner but lately it does it with two of the burners. I did check if there were any wires that was burned but couldn't find anything.

Then what it did next was to try and swap the faulty burners with one of the burners that was working without overloading and tripping my breaker, and when I switched the plate on it didn't trip my breaker. Is it possible that the fault can be on the burner itself or is it somewhere else that i need to look into?

Answer (score 1):

The resistive plates are the main wearing element on an electric stove.  That is why they are made to be not expensive and easily replaced.

If one is tripping your 40-50A stove breaker, **stop using it**. Repeatedly tripping a breaker to see what happens will tend to destroy things which are not yet broken -- since you are, after all, surging well north of 100,000 watts of power through equipment rated for 1/10 that.  Why are people so unafraid of electricity?